# AirDrop - Custom file app not installed (for receiver)

Tags: objective-c, uti, airdrop, uiactivitytypeairdrop

After .plist UTI configuration for sharing a custom object, The receiver gets a message:

> "the sender would like to share a file that requires an app from the App
> Store"

I can guess I missing something related to bundle identifier, but without success.

where is my error? what can lead to this error?

[image]

**Details:**

- I'm testing on two devices
- The app is installed on two devices.
- The file is generate from my app.
- The is custom UTI.
  [image]

[image]

Comment: *"After configure for AirDrop"* - what does this mean? Provide more details in your question. How are you sending the file (I know it's AirDrop but what code is used to send it)? Is the file generated from your app and is the file's UTI custom to your app?

Comment: @HangarRash thank you for responding. I've added extra details

Comment: OK. The displayed message seems right to me assuming the receiver of your custom file doesn't yet have your app installed. You are sending a file that only your app knows about so the receiver can do one of two things. Open it in your app or save it as a file. Those are the two choices being presented to the user. What are you expecting to happen differently here? And what error are you referring to? There is no error being shown.

Comment: @HangarRash, The application is installed for the receiver as well. (I'm testing on 2 devices)